# Why shared int variable show atomic behavior when incrementing it in go routine?

Tags: go

when I run the following code snippet below, it looks it always prints the value 20000000. It shows similar behavior when I create more go routines to increment the counter without lock. But shouldn't there exist some kind of race condition ?  Thanks !

```
package main

import "fmt"

const (
N_INCREMENTS = 10000000
)

func main() {

var counter int = 0
donechan := make(chan bool)

go func(done chan<- bool) {
    for i := 0; i < N_INCREMENTS; i++ {
        counter++
    }
    done <- true
}(donechan)

for i := 0; i < N_INCREMENTS; i++ {
    counter++
}

_ = <-donechan

fmt.Println("Count: ", counter)
}
```

Comment: What is the value of [`GOMAXPROCS`](https://godoc.org/runtime#GOMAXPROCS)?

Comment: I didn't set this variable, but inspired by you, I tried `GOMAXPROCS=2`,  and it shows race condition now (print < 20000000).  So does that indicate the default value might be 1, which indicates only a single OS thread will be used to execute the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) will report you the number of goroutines that can be run parallel. If the value is 1, you may not observe any "side effect" of not synchronizing the `counter` variable.

If first at the beginning of your program you set it to `2`:

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
```

You will immediately see the effect:

```
Count:  10319575
```

If you want to have proof of the race condition, supply the `-race` argument. The output with `-race`:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read by goroutine 6:
  main.main.func1()
      V:/workspace/IczaGo/src/play/play.go:20 +0x48

Previous write by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      V:/workspace/IczaGo/src/play/play.go:26 +0xef

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      V:/workspace/IczaGo/src/play/play.go:23 +0xbc
==================
```

(Note that the race detector only works with 64-bit Go distributions.)

On the Go playground, GOMAXPROCS is `1` by default. This line will print the previous value and set it to `2`:

```
fmt.Println("Previous GOMAXPROCS:", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qZy6s9J0y0)):

```
Previous GOMAXPROCS: 1
Count:  12844130
```

Also note that GOMAXPROCS is set to `1` in Go distributions prior to 1.5. Starting with 1.5 the default value of GOMAXPROCS is the number of CPU cores available on the machine running the program.

Comment: Thanks very much !  Yes my GOMAXPROCS is set to 1.   So for a large scale project where we may use go routine excessively,  should we have to manually specify the value of GOMAXPROCS ?   Not setting that value may result in a completely "single thread" program ?

Comment: @morefree Please read the last paragraph of my answer. If you use Go 1.5+, it is set to the number of CPU cores by default. Using <1.5, it is set to 1 by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  that's really helpful